# Textarea regular expression

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I need to test a textarea to accept the following.

New Line `\n`, space `\s`, `a-zA-Z, 0-9,? $@#()'!,+-/=_:.&€£*` and `%`.

**Edited:** So far tried:

```
var regx = a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\-=_:.&€£*%\s ;

/*don't know the method for checking regular expression
  So, some method like validate_regex to check/match
*/

regx.validate_regex(my_textbox_value);
```

Please answer how to write the regular expression for this using php and jquery.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `textbox-id` to be the id of your `textarea`

```
var textboxValue = $("#textbox-id").val();
var regx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\-=_:.&€£*%\s]+$/;

if (regx.test(textboxValue))
    alert("correct"); // alerts
else
    alert('Incorrect!');​
```

Try this one:

HTML:

```
<textarea  id="foo"> </textarea>

<input type="text" id="bar"/>
```

JS:

```
var regx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9?$@#()'!,+\-=_:.&€£*%\s]+$/;

$('#foo').keyup(function() {
    if (regx.test(this.value)) $('#bar').val('correct');
    else  $('#bar').val('incorrect');
});
```

**Edited:** Here is the Updated [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yHSQF/2/)

Comment: Seems like you want only this, don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: There is something wrong here `+-=`. This defines a range. So either you escape the hyphen `+\-=` or you put it at the end of your character class.

Comment: did you try the the DEMO ?

Comment: `,+-=_` will match more than you think. There is range declared in there. Take a look at the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), `+-=` will match from `+` to `=` which means it will match some digits and other characters including `<` which is not what the OP wanted. Take a look at this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aI8cM9). The solution is to escape `-` or put it at the end of your character class `[,+=_-]`.

Comment: ah, i didn't consider it before, now i got the thing. Really nice observation. +1 for that

Comment: can i get an upvote ? :)